# Query multiple lines of a database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am making a tetris game in c# and I would like to add a ranking with the 5 best players.

For this I have made 2 tables: Users (userName and psw) and Score(id, userName and psw). And I use this code, but it gives me the following error.

```
        string result = "";
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conexionString);
        conexion.Open();

        string getScoreRankingCommand = "SELECT TOP 5 userName FROM Score LIMIT5 ORDER BY score DESC;";
        SqlCommand top5 = new SqlCommand(getScoreRankingCommand, conexion);

        try {
            
            SqlDataReader reader = top5.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show(( string )top5.ExecuteScalar());

        }

        catch (Exception ex) {

            MessageBox.Show("Consult of the top 5 BEST PLAYERS IN THE WORLD failed: " + ex.Message + ".");

        }

        conexion.Close();
        return result;
```

And the error message:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
> must be closed first.

I have tried it in many ways and looking at many tutorials/documentation/forums, but it does not work out for me. I would like to get something like this:

```
user 1    99 points
user 2    21 points
user 3    21 points
user 2    12 points
user 3    4 points
```

Thanks for help

)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The return value of `top5.ExecuteReader` gives you your results, you shouldn't then execute `top5.ExecuteScalar` Use your `reader` object here to get the data.

Comment: You are using Sql Server whats the point of _LIMIT5_ a MySql statement? (and also typed wrongly)

Comment: Either use `ExecuteReader` **or** `ExecuteScalar` but not both of them. There should be a space in `LIMIT5` like `LIMIT 5` but it is obsolete anyway, since you already have the `TOP 5` clause. Write `using SqlConnection conexion = ...`. This will close and dispose the connection automatically at the end of the scope where this variable is declared.

Comment: `ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column of the first row in the result set and ignores the remainder of the rows/columns. The commented out while loop is a way to process all 5 rows but you need to retrieve the column values of each row from the reader in each iteration (e.g. `reader["userName"]` instead of `ExecuteScalar` (which executes the query again). I think you need a separate question on how to write the query to return all the data. That question should include the CREATE TABLE statements, the query you tried, and sample results.

Comment: Querying and the querying again for dependant data when all this can be done in a single query with `JOIN` sounds like an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really easy. I send the pseudocode in case it helps someone.

```
string pseudoCode() {

       string result = "";
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(path);
       con.Open();

       string com = "SELECT TOP 5 user, score FROM table2 ORDER BY socre DESC;"
       SqlCommand top5 = new SqlCommand(com, con);

       try {

           SqlDataReader r = top5.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read()) {

              // Add the lines of output in the result string.
              // In this way you can return all the lines generated by the query
              result = result + ((string) reader["username"] + reader["score"])  + "\n";
           }}

       // TODO: catch () {}

      con.Close();
      return result;
}
```